# Plotting pandas dataframe with boolean categorical time-series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a pandas dataframe of the form

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2021-02-01', end='2021-03-14', freq='D')
df['specimen1'] = 0
df['specimen2'] = 0
df['specimen3'] = 0

df['specimen1'].loc[(df.date >= '2021-02-01') & (df.date <= '2021-02-03')] = 1
df['specimen3'].loc[(df.date >= '2021-02-02') & (df.date <= '2021-02-05')] = 1
df['specimen2'].loc[(df.date >= '2021-02-10') & (df.date <= '2021-02-20')] = 1
df = df.set_index('date')

df.head()
```

[image]

where `df` contains time series data. The columns contain booleans (true/false) for different specimens (categorical data). How do I plot this using seaborn or matplotlib? I want the categories on the x-axis and dates on y-axis -- there should be a vertical line for each `specimen` to represent the date range that fulfils the `True` condition. In seaborn I tried

```
 sns.catplot(data=df)
```

but this gives me:

[image]

because it doesn't want to plot the dates on the y-axis.

Comment: Try **not setting** the date as index

Comment: I still get the same graph

Comment: I'm not really wellversed with Seaborn, but I see catplot accepts x and y columns. Try explicitly declare them. Something like `sns.catplot(x='date', y=['specimen1', 'specimen2', 'specimen3'], data=df)`

Comment: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to visualize the data as heatmap.

### Code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2021-02-01', end='2021-03-14', freq='D')
df['specimen1'] = 0
df['specimen2'] = 0
df['specimen3'] = 0

df['specimen1'].loc[(df.date >= '2021-02-01') & (df.date <= '2021-02-03')] = 1
df['specimen3'].loc[(df.date >= '2021-02-02') & (df.date <= '2021-02-05')] = 1
df['specimen2'].loc[(df.date >= '2021-02-10') & (df.date <= '2021-02-20')] = 1

df['date'] = df['date'].dt.date
df = df.set_index('date')

# Visualize the data as heatmap
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 14
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(9, 16))
sns.heatmap(df, cmap=sns.light_palette('lightblue'), cbar=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel('Specimen')
ax.set_ylabel('Date')
ax.set_yticks([i for i in range(len(df))], [i for i in df.index.values])

plt.show()

# Save the figure
# fig.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight', facecolor='white')
```

### Figure:

[image]